# Como guardar un archivo xls en una variable , para luego transformarlo a xlsx

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx, xls

*Saludos cordiales gente, tengo este problema , uso aspx V4.

Tengo un método donde se genera un archivo excel "xls" el cual no es soportado por tablets y algunos Android celulares, esto lo hace a través de un RESPONSE.

Por lo que opte por hacer una conversión dentro del código a xlsx, pero para esto :
Como almaceno mi doc excel(output) en una VARIABLE temporal , O como podría sacar el doc generado de esta RESPONSE, antes de ser descargado a la PC del cliente, para hacer dicha conversión.*

Este es el código no esta completo porque es demasiado grande, pero para una idea.

```
            for (i = 1; i <= TotalDias; i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;'>&nbsp;</td>");
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'><b>RUT</b></td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'><b>NOMBRES</b></td>");

            int w = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= TotalDias; i++)
            {
                if (FechaMuestra.AddDays(w).DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
                {
                    fechamuestra = FechaMuestra.AddDays(w).ToString("dd");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;color:red;'><b>" + fechamuestra + "</b></td>");
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;'><b>" + FechaMuestra.AddDays(w).ToString("dd") + "</b></td>");
                }
                w++;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'><b>TOTAL</b></td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                resultadoefeB[i] = 0;
                resultadoefeA[i] = 0;
            }

            for (x = 0; x < dtAllExcel.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + dtAllExcel.Rows[x]["Rut"].ToString().ToUpper() + "</td>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>" + dtAllExcel.Rows[x]["Apellido"].ToString().ToUpper() + " " + dtAllExcel.Rows[x]["Nombre"].ToString().ToUpper() + "</td>");

                for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                {
                    arrRegleta[i] = "";
                }

                DataTable dtArchivo = negocio.BuscarHorasControladas(int.Parse(dtAllExcel.Rows[x]["IdGuardia"].ToString()), item.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(inputFechaDesde.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(inputFechaHasta.Text));

                decimal suma = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < dtArchivo.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int dia = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDateTime(dtArchivo.Rows[i]["Fecha"]).ToString("dd"));

                    DateTime fechainicioG = DateTime.Parse(inputFechaDesde.Text);
                    string ff = dtArchivo.Rows[i]["Fecha"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) + "-" + dtArchivo.Rows[i]["Fecha"].ToString().Substring(3, 2) + "-" + dtArchivo.Rows[i]["Fecha"].ToString().Substring(6, 4);
                    DateTime fechafinG = DateTime.Parse(ff);


                    result = (fechafinG - fechainicioG);

                    indice = Convert.ToInt32(result.TotalDays.ToString()) + 1;

                    if (dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() == "")
                    {
                        valorE = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        valorE = Convert.ToDecimal(dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
                    }

                    if (dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        if (dtArchivo.Rows[i]["IdTipoTurno"].ToString() == "1")
                        {
                            arrRegleta[indice] += "<span title='Adicional' style='color:blue;font-weight: bold;'>" + dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() + "</span><br/>";
                            resultadoefeA[indice] += valorE;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            arrRegleta[indice] += dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                            resultadoefeB[indice] += valorE;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrRegleta[indice] = "";
                    }

                    if (dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "VA" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "LM" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "VP" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "M" &&

                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "PG" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "SG" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "I" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "N" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "PF" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "PM" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "R" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "EM" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "PS" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "MP" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "DL" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "A" &&

                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "F" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "NI" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "TP" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "EP" &&

                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "EC" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "PA" &&

                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "D" &&
                        dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString() != "CD")
                    {
                        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
                        arrTotalHoras[indice] += Convert.ToDecimal(dtArchivo.Rows[i]["TotalHora"].ToString().Replace(".", ","));
                    }
                }

                for (int z = 1; z <= TotalDias; z++)
                {
                    if (arrRegleta[z] == null)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>&nbsp;</td>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;width:22px;'>" + arrRegleta[z].ToString() + "</td>");
                    }
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + suma + "</td>");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");
            }

            decimal totali = 0;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS SOLICITADAS BÁSICAS:</b></td>");

            DateTime Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(inputFechaDesde.Text);
            DataTable dtHorasBasica;

            decimal totalBasicas = 0;

            _basica = 0;
            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                dtHorasBasica = negocio.BuscarDiaMallaServicioBasica(Fecha.AddDays(_basica), int.Parse(item.Value), out error, out glosa);
                resultado = 0;
                resultadoA = 0;
                if (dtHorasBasica.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    resultado = (Convert.ToDecimal(dtHorasBasica.Rows[0]["NUMEROHORASB"]) - (Convert.ToDecimal(dtHorasBasica.Rows[0]["COLACION"]) / 60));
                    resultadoFinal[t] = resultadoFinal[t] + resultado;

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + resultado + "</td>");

                    if (resultado == 0)
                    {
                        totalBasicas += 0;
                        arrTotalHorasB[t] = resultado;
                        arrTotalHoras[t] = resultado;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalBasicas += resultado;
                        arrTotalHorasB[t] = resultado;
                        arrTotalHoras[t] = resultado;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>0</td>");
                }
                _basica++;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + totalBasicas + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS SOLICITADAS ADICIONAL:</b></td>");

            DataTable dtHorasAdicional;

            decimal totalAdicional = 0;

            _adicional = 0;
            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                dtHorasAdicional = negocio.BuscarDiaMallaServicioAdicional(Fecha.AddDays(_adicional), int.Parse(item.Value), out error, out glosa);

                if (dtHorasAdicional.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    resultadoA = (Convert.ToDecimal(dtHorasAdicional.Rows[0]["NUMEROHORASA"]) - (Convert.ToDecimal(dtHorasAdicional.Rows[0]["COLACION"]) / 60));
                    resultadoFinal[t] = resultadoFinal[t] + resultadoA;

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + resultadoA + "</td>");

                    if (resultadoA == 0)
                    {
                        totalAdicional += 0;
                        arrTotalHorasA[t] += resultadoA;
                        arrTotalHoras[t] += resultadoA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        totalAdicional += resultadoA;
                        arrTotalHorasA[t] += resultadoA;
                        arrTotalHoras[t] += resultadoA;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>0</td>");
                }
                _adicional++;
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + totalAdicional + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            //TOTAL SOLICITADO
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='background-color: yellow; text-align:right;'><b>TOTAL SOLICITADO:</b></td>");

            decimal totalSolicitado = 0;

            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;background-color: yellow;'>" + arrTotalHoras[t] + "</td>");
                totalSolicitado += arrTotalHoras[t];
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;background-color: yellow;'>" + totalSolicitado + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS EFECTUADAS BÁSICAS:</b></td>");

            decimal totalSolicitadas = 0;
            decimal totalMenos = 0;
            decimal totalMas = 0;

            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + resultadoefeB[t] + "</td>");
                totalSolicitadas = totalSolicitadas + resultadoefeB[t];
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + totalSolicitadas + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS EFECTUADAS ADICIONAL:</b></td>");

            for (int y = 1; y <= TotalDias; y++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;width:28px;'>" + resultadoefeA[y] + "</td>");
                totali += resultadoefeA[y];

                decimal diferencia = arrTotalHoras[y] - (resultadoefeA[y] + resultadoefeB[y]);

                if (diferencia > 0)
                {
                    arrHorasMenos[y] = diferencia;
                    totalMenos = totalMenos + diferencia;
                    arrHorasMas[y] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    diferencia = diferencia * -1;
                    arrHorasMas[y] = diferencia;
                    arrHorasMenos[y] = 0;
                    totalMas = totalMas + diferencia;
                }
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + totali + "</td>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS DE MENOS:</b></td>");

            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + arrHorasMenos[t] + "</td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center'>" + totalMenos + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            //TOTAL EFECTUADO
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='background-color: yellow; text-align:right;'><b>TOTAL EFECTUADO:</b></td>");

            decimal totalEfectuado = 0;

            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;background-color: yellow;'>" + (resultadoefeB[t] + resultadoefeA[t]) + "</td>");
                totalEfectuado += resultadoefeB[t] + resultadoefeA[t];
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;background-color: yellow;'>" + totalEfectuado + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:right;'><b>HORAS DE MÁS:</b></td>");

            for (int t = 1; t <= TotalDias; t++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + arrHorasMas[t] + "</td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='text-align:center;'>" + totalMas + "</td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
            for (i = 1; i <= (TotalDias + 3); i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td style='background-color:#CEECF5'>&nbsp;</td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");
        }
    }
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</table>");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: Podrias agregar un flujo de como estas trabajando los archivos, no entiendo porque al usuario le devuelves un xls.

Comment: @MiguelZarate estoy un poco limitado, es un evento onclick(boton-aspx) .... creo que seria un poco extenso explicarlo , pero bueno.
principalmente se trata de crear un EXCEL , se le pasa el contentType ,de manera que pueda expulsar un EXCEL XLSX , mas la extensión de archivo(.xlsx), pero esta RESPONSE al estar hecha como HTML y no XML no podre generar el output con el formato requerido,  solo puede generar un XLS , y esto no funciona con los nuevos Excel de office.
si conociera una manera de tomar esta response , transformarla en un archivo.xls, sin guardarlo en alguna carpeta seria genial

Comment: Si tienes accesso al codigo del lado del servidor puedes generar la respuesta con la extension que gustes, entonces seria un boton de descargar excel y ese archivo tu lo generas del lado del servidor y el usuario lo descarga,